# Dropdown display output

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have 2 dropdown, What I need is when a user select an option from the 2 dropdown. When a user clicks the button GO, it will display it selected option respectively

I want it to be like this, I'm only using label for better understanding

```html
<label for="bl" class="control-label col-xs-3"><p class="left">Branch:</p></label><p>Branch A</p>

<label for="bl" class="control-label col-xs-3"><p class="left">Category:</p></label><p>Stock</p>
```

my brand dropdown is actually php.

Well here's my dropdown

```html
<div class="col-xs-8">
<div class="req">
 <select name="bid" class="form-control">
<option value="" default style="color:gray;">Branch</option>
<option value="brancha">Branch A</option>
<option value="branchb">Branch B</option>
<option value="branchc">Branch C</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>

   <div class="col-xs-8">
 <div class="req">
     <select name="brcat" class="form-control">
 <option value="" default style="color:gray;">Category</option>
 <option value="Stock">Stock</option>
 <option value="Sales">Sales</option>
 <option value="Stock Transfer">Stock Transfer</option>
 </select>
 </div>
 </div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default bt" style="align:right;">Go</button>
```

Comment: Both your dropdowns are named brcat. Standard practice is to give them ids, then query the value of the id using a selector. e.g., <select id="categoryDropdown"... then document.querySelector('#categoryDropdown').value will tell you what you need. You will need a click handler on your go button too, and you don't need to round trip to the server. Do this clientside. If this is inside a form, your button type=submit will auto-post. So remove that attribute and add an onclick.

Comment: Ohh sorry, I updated the code, they supposed to be different id, thanks! :D

Comment: If you are using jquery, just add <p id=categoryChoice>Stock</p> then
$('#goButton').on('click',function(){$('#categoryChoice').html($('#categoryDropdown').val());})

Comment: @RonGilchrist I don't have any jquery function atm

Comment: Your question is tagged with jquery and you are using bootstrap classes which have a jquery dependancy. It's dirt simple. Doing this client side is what you want. Ultimately this is something that mvc frameworks like angular, knockout, backbone, etc. do very well. My above approach is good for a one-off, but as things grow, it gets unweildy. I would spend some time reading up on data-binding and templates, etc. It will help you in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery Selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) to search and match the elements in a document. For example, you can get the value of an element by using [ID Selectors](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) when you add an `id` to it:

```js
$('#go_btn').on('click', function(){
  var branch = $('#branch_opt option:selected').val();
  var category = $('#category_opt option:selected').val();
  $('#branch_div').html('Branch : '+branch);
  $('#category_div').html('Category : '+category);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="branch_opt">
  <option value="">Branch</option>
  <option value="brancha">Branch A</option>
  <option value="branchb">Branch B</option>
  <option value="branchc">Branch C</option>
</select>

<select id="category_opt">
  <option value="">Category</option>
  <option value="Stock">Stock</option>
  <option value="Sales">Sales</option>
  <option value="Stock Transfer">Stock Transfer</option>
</select>

<input type="button" id="go_btn" value="Go">

<div id="branch_div"></div>
<div id="category_div"></div>
```

Comment: Is this working also when I'm using php for dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

I am having a hard time determining what it is your trying to accomplish. If I am understanding your question, you want to have a particular option on your drop down selected?

```
<option value="" selected="yes" style="color:gray;">Category</option>
```

Comment: No, when a user selected options from two dropdowns, the page will reload and will display the output just like the first code that I discussed. Don't bother with the reload thing :)